# Will I get a tax form for sale of direct purchased stock (US)?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, capital-gains-tax

I had some stock in a company (Questar) that I gained over a period of many years via directly purchasing the stock from Questar.  Last year Questar was acquired by another company and so I was forced to sell all my Questar stock.  I haven't received any form showing capital gains/losses for the sale of this stock.  It's only Jan. 30 so there's still a few more days that the document could arrive, but as I sit here waiting I realize I don't even know what I'm looking for.

On which document is reported capital gains/losses?  For directly purchased and directly sold stock, would this document come from the company that issues the stock?  And if the company was acquired by another company, would that affect how I would be receiving this document?

I already received a 1099-DIV from Questar back in December detailing the dividends issued to me by Questar, but that contained no information about the capital gains/loss from selling the stock.

I do not know from the records I have if the stock sale resulted in a capital gain or loss.  Would I expect different forms in each case?

**Edit:** The stocks were sold for cash.  I received a check in the mail.

(I understand and acknowledge that any answers or comments given here are not to be construed as official and legal tax advice.  I assume all consequences for decisions made based on information, possibly imperfect, given here).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I found the answer, at least in my specific case.

From [the heading "Questar/Dominion Resources Merger" in this linked website](https://www.dom.com/search#q=1099-b):

> Q: When will I receive tax forms showing the stock and dividend payments?
>
> A: You can expect a Form 1099-B in early February 2017 showing the amount associated with payment of your
>   shares. You also will receive a Form 1099-DIV by Jan. 31, 2017, with your 2016 dividends earned.